# picture resolution to a canvas print

Tags: printing, canvas

i would like a picture on a canvas print 40inch x 22inch. The picture is 96dpi. Will this be okay to get a good clear picture, if not what would be??
many thanks

Comment: It depends on the photo and the distance at which the photo will be viewed from...

Comment: While this is canvas rather than a typical inkjet print.  The existing posts on print resolution still apply equally to inkjet or canvas printing, particularly since a lot of canvas prints are done using inkjet technology.